# Filter: Select task updated since last viewed

Tags: jira, jql

I am looking to create a filter that will retrieve all tasks that have been updated since the last time the current user viewed them.

I have access to the "Last Viewed" field in my widgets on the dashboard, but I can't access it when I create a filter.

I would like to use something like the following:

```
filter = 11013 AND updated > LastViewed
```

But this doesn't work. Is this something we can do using Jira?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is make a big(infinite) value on your updated field as it just uses a range of date or number of days, weeks minutes and etc.

Something like this:

```
assignee in (currentUser()) and updated >= "-500w" ORDER BY lastViewed DESC
```